# ruamel.yaml dump doesn't preserve boolean value case

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a simple python 2.7.12 script running on both linux and osx providing the same output.  When using ruamel during the dump, the value of a boolean seems to convert to all lowercase.  As a test when the field is converted to an unquoted string there is no case conversion.

File: **test.yml**

```yaml
namespace: default
testapp_appname: testapp

images:
  testapp:
    path: "foo/testapp"
    tag: "202120810083053-1.2.3"

testapp_replicas: 1

testapp_monitoring_enabled: False
testapp_node_selector: ""
```

My simple test script:

```py
import ruamel
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()


def main():
    config_path = "test.yml"
    image = "testapp"
    timestamp = "202120810083053-"
    version = "1.2.3"
    config = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(open(config_path), preserve_quotes=True)
    config['images'][image]['tag'] = "{}{}".format(timestamp, version)
    ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Input:**

`testapp_monitoring_enabled: False`

**Output:**

`testapp_monitoring_enabled: false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the new API ( `yaml = YAML()` ) with the old API (`ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump()`), that is possible but not necessary (nor recommended).

`ruamel.yaml` doesn't preserve the casing of your booleans (`False`, `FALSE`), but it is possible to set the values used in the dump using the boolean_representation attribute (this of course affects all booleans):

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.boolean_representation = ['False', 'True']

def main():
    config_path = "test.yml"
    image = "testapp"
    timestamp = "202120810083053-"
    version = "1.2.3"
    config = yaml.load(open(config_path))
    config['images'][image]['tag'] = "{}{}".format(timestamp, version)
    yaml.dump(config, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

will get you:

```
namespace: default
testapp_appname: testapp

images:
  testapp:
    path: "foo/testapp"
    tag: "202120810083053-1.2.3"

testapp_replicas: 1

testapp_monitoring_enabled: False
testapp_node_selector: ""
```

Comment: thanks for the note about mixing the calls.  Chalk it up to copy/paste from SO.  This is confirmed to work in keeping my booleans nice and formatted the way we need.

Comment: BTW, if you want to remove the final newline with the new API, you should do: `yaml.dump(config, sys.stdout, transform=lambda data: data.rstrip())`

Comment: its like you read my mind as I was trying to figure out how to do this with the newer API.  So my command of `yaml.dump(config, stream=open(config_path, 'w'), transform=lambda data: data.rstrip())` does exactly what I want.